# Is getting GPS data from mobile browser known to be somewhat flaky?

Tags: mobile, geolocation, location, mobile-safari, geo

I currently have WORKING code where when user presses a button to share their location, the browser pops out a "Would you like to share your location?" and then the front end code handles the result. (HTML5 Geolocation API)

I have noticed that the failure rate is about 10%, by which I mean rate at which either `position_unavailable` triggers, or the unknown error in the code below:

```
$("#share-location-btn").click(shareLocation);

function shareLocation() {
  $("#share-location-btn").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#checking-location-msg").removeClass("hidden");

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(validateLocation, handleGeolocationError);
}

function handleGeolocationError(error) {
  let errorText;
  switch(error.code) {
  case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
    errorText = "Location sharing was denied";
    break;

  case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
    errorText = "Location can't be determined - contact us at XXX-XXX-XXXX";
    break;

  default:
    errorText = "Unknown error - contact us at XXX-XXX-XXXX";
    break;
  }
  errorUIHelper(errorText);
}
```

I'm trying to reduce the failure rate more. I feel like this must be possible, because services like bike sharing apps (e.g., Lime) literally require a GPS for every unlock action, and given how they do NOT have on-demand customer service for when this doesn't work, I'm assuming they have achieved a super low failure rate.

However, these services are of course apps. I understand that apps offer a lot more flexibility for geofencing services in general (e.g., location can be continually sent even when phone is locked, rather than requiring a user interaction).

That said, I kind of want to confirm, with people who are more experienced in doing geofencing on mobile browsers, NOT apps... is the mobile browser just known to be flaky? Because there are so many possible permutations of mobile device, operating system, browser, etc.?

And if this results in migration to an app, are apps also known to be generally less flaky in this regard?

Comment: I cannot directly answer to your question yet, as I didn't work much with web apps. However, there are a few things that I can say.

I can confirm that you can achieve a very low error rate in an app (not a web app).

However, Android devices are beasts. Even big brands sprinkles API's with unexpected behaviour. Perhaps, the behaviour you are observing happens only with this brand/model.

Comment: thanks for the comment! yes I imagine Android would be trickier since there are so many more devices possible... sigh